# User Defined Function Return value

Tags: sql-server-2008, functions

Hello all I have a function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getContentURL]
(
    @VID    int,
    @accountID int
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @cTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].CONTENT_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
    DECLARE @vTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].VERSION_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) =  ''
DECLARE @RETURN VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition VARCHAR(500)
 SET @sql = '
    DECLARE @CompanyID int
    DECLARE @RETURN VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @ProjectNumber int
    DECLARE @ContentID int
    DECLARE @VersionNumber int
    DECLARE @FileName varchar(400)
  select @VersionNumber= V.Number,@ContentID= V.ContentID,@ProjectNumber=P.Number,@FileName=C.Name,@CompanyID=P.CompanyID 
    from ' + @vTable + ' V 
    inner join' + @cTable + ' C on V.ContentID=C.ID
    inner join Project P on C.ProjectID=P.ID where V.VID='+convert(varchar,@VID)+'

 select ''/''+Convert(varchar,@CompanyID)+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ProjectNumber)+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ContentID)+''/''+Convert(varchar,@VersionNumber)+''/''+@FileName'


 SET @ParmDefinition = N'@RETURN VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition,  @RETURN OUTPUT
  set @RETURN=(select @RETURN)
 RETURN @RETURN
END
```

but when I execute this function

```
select  dbo.getContentURL(177,1)
```

this gives error:

```
The name 'select --------------------' is not a valid identifier.
```

how to return this executed value? can any one  help me please?

Comment: You can't use dynamic SQL in functions and would need to use `EXEC()` even if you could. But it doesn't look like it needs it anyway. What is ` --------------------` supposed to be? Also how do you intend to use this? scalar UDFS that do data access can be performance killers.

Comment: ya within '-------------' im creating dynamic tablename depending on @VID so... Can I have any altenate solution for this?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not permitted in functions so you won't be able to do this. Maybe you could use a View partitioned on `@VID` please explain more about your situation.

Comment: I have edited my question, here is my actual Function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that I understand what it is that You are trying to do...
The thing is, just like You have already been told, that You can't use Dynamic SQL in a Function.

Using a Stored Procedure will solve the problem You encountered:
(I did not try to find another logic to retrieving the same data, which is possible, I just converted Your Function to a Stored Procedure)

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_getContentURL] 
(@VID INT, @accountID INT) 
AS 
DECLARE @cTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].CONTENT_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
DECLARE @vTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].VERSION_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) =  '' 
SET @sql = ' 
DECLARE @CompanyID int
DECLARE @ProjectNumber int
DECLARE @ContentID int
DECLARE @VersionNumber int
DECLARE @FileName varchar(400)
select @VersionNumber=V.Number, @ContentID=V.ContentID, @ProjectNumber=P.Number, @FileName=C.Name, @CompanyID=P.CompanyID
from ' + @vTable + ' V
inner join' + @cTable + ' C on V.ContentID=C.ID
inner join Project P on C.ProjectID=P.ID 
where V.VID='+convert(varchar,@VID)+' 
select ''/''+Convert(varchar,@CompanyID)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ProjectNumber)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ContentID)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@VersionNumber)
+''/''+@FileName'

EXEC (@sql)
GO
```

If this does not meet Your needs please post what exactly You are trying to do.
Good Luck,
Roi

Answer (score 1):

you can't use dynamic SQL in functions, for best understanding to solve your problem [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639559/sql-not-valid-identifier-error)

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_getContentURL] 
(@VID INT, @accountID INT) 
AS 
DECLARE @cTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].CONTENT_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
DECLARE @vTable varchar(50) = '[CONTENT_CONNECT].[dbo].VERSION_' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@accountID)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) =  '' 
SET @sql = ' 
DECLARE @CompanyID int
DECLARE @ProjectNumber int
DECLARE @ContentID int
DECLARE @VersionNumber int
DECLARE @FileName varchar(400)
select @VersionNumber=V.Number, @ContentID=V.ContentID, @ProjectNumber=P.Number, @FileName=C.Name, @CompanyID=P.CompanyID
from ' + @vTable + ' V
inner join' + @cTable + ' C on V.ContentID=C.ID
inner join Project P on C.ProjectID=P.ID 
where V.VID='+convert(varchar,@VID)+' 
select ''/''+Convert(varchar,@CompanyID)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ProjectNumber)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@ContentID)
+''/''+Convert(varchar,@VersionNumber)
+''/''+@FileName'

EXEC (@sql)
GO
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: I diffed them just in case there was some difference and they are identical